# Activity.Current.AddTag() issue..... Singleton related?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I hope I can explain this issue well enough to prompt for an answer to my issue.

I have an Azure function(V4) that uses CosmosDBTrigger written in C#. We're seeing the same issue in other function types as well.

In order to add custom properties in Application Insights RequestTelemetry we're using an activity tagger. It is built as a singleton in the function start up.

In the function, I am adding a tag with the salesTransactionNumber from the document I've read, then further down in the code I log that the transaction number has been written to the service bus.

The issue is that it appears that the first time the activity tagger is called, it has the correct transaction number. After that, it could be correct, or it could have the same transaction number as the previous document. The logged informational messages always have the correct transaction number.

The issue is with this line of code in the function shown below. It is adding the wrong transaction number to customDimensions:

```
_activityTagger.AddTag("SaleTransactionNumber", sale.Header.TransactionNumber);
```

Here's the activity tagger's code:

```
void AddTag(string key, string value)
{
    Activity.Current?.AddTag(key, value);
}
```

And here's a snippet of the function (changefeed):

```
    public class ServiceBusNotifier
    {
        private readonly IActivityTagger _activityTagger;

        public ServiceBusNotifier(
            IActivityTagger activityTagger
            )
        {
            _activityTagger = activityTagger;
        }

        [FunctionName("ServiceBusNotifier")]
        public async Task RunAsync([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "%CosmosDb:DatabaseId%",
            collectionName: "%masterCollectionName%",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "cosmosdb-connection",
            LeaseCollectionName = "%leasesCollectionName%",
            LeaseCollectionPrefix = "ServiceBusNotifier")] IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, ILogger logger)
        {
            try
            {
                if (documents != null && documents.Any())
                {
                    var callbackBasePath = _configuration.CallbackBaseUrl;

                    await Task.WhenAll(documents.Select(async document =>
                    {
                        var sale = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sale>(document.ToString());

                        _activityTagger.AddTag("SaleTransactionNumber", sale.Header.TransactionNumber);
                        logger.LogInformation($"Sending Service Bus Message for Sales change for TransactionNumber {sale.Header.TransactionNumber}");

                        Message build logic...
                        
                        await _serviceBusClient.SendJsonMessageAsync(message, userProperties, messageId);
                        logger.LogInformation($"Sent Service Bus Message: {messageId}  TransactionNumber: {sale.Header.TransactionNumber}");
                    }));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with the activityTagger as a singleton, or perhaps it has to do with the loop processing all documents? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You setting tag at the same instance of activity. `Activity.Current` is singleton, if you doesn't intiate new activity for each document.

Comment: I realize that it's a singleton. What type of change do I need to make to initiate new activity for each document?

Comment: Check `ActivitySource` docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activitysource?view=net-6.0
Note, that activity which you will create should be tracked. If it's not, methods of `ActivitySource` that creates `Activity` will return `null`.